# Image Rewriting

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

This is probably more of a check than a question, but is the following correct:

```
RewriteRule ^_images/(.*)_(.*)_(.*)$ /_images/$2_$3 [L]
```

Basically I want to automatically make webpages use `/_images/picture-name_ABC123_600.jpg` (which doesn't really exist) but actually use the image `/_images/ABC123_600.jpg` that does exist.

I gave it a check locally in XAMPP, and worked, however I though that I'd better try adding more underscores eg. `/_images/picture-name_A_B_C_1_2_3_600.jpg` which I was expecting to work, yet the image still appeared - so is this normal behavour?

I'm also not too sure if I can use an underscore between the two dollar signs above...

Any help would be great!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will not work as the `(.*)` is greedy and matches as many characters as it can, even underscores. Something like this (not allowing underscore between the separators):

```
RewriteRule ^_images/([^_]*)_([^_]*)_([^_]*)$ /_images/$2_$3 [L]
```

or this (ungreedy matching):

```
RewriteRule ^_images/(.*?)_(.*?)_(.*?)$ /_images/$2_$3 [L]
```

or a combination of both should work. (Depending of what chars are allowed within each block)